# Clone jsfiddle example

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I'm trying clone this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/codearachnid/Le1jk85q/) in my source but not working. All external links is added.

My HTML source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brinley/jSignature/master/libs/jSignature.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>


    <div id="wrapper">

        <div ng-controller="SignatureController">
            <div>items length: {{items.length}}</div>
            <img ng-src="{{hash}}" alt="signature image" />

            <j-signature-directive sig="customSignature" save="testAction" bg-color="#00f" color="#ffcc00"></j-signature-directive>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs">
            <div class="tCont result active" id="result"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                    if (typeof (EmbedManager) === undefined) {

                        EmbedManager.loadResult();

                    }
                }, false);
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In app.js file is all from javascript from above link.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @SatejS signature is not disply!

Comment: Errors in console?

Comment: @SatejS no error in console,my online example here http:/ /goo.gl/DXymzO

Comment: @SatejS signature is not vissible in my example, that is problem!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to place all your code in JS file inside
`$(document).ready( function() { ... });`